# service worker show notification not working

Tags: javascript, service-worker

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js').then((reg) => {

})



Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
    console.log('User Choice', result);
    if (result !== 'granted') {
      console.log('No notification permission granted!');
    } else {
        navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(function(swreg) {
            console.log("blaxblux");
          swreg.showNotification('Successfully subscribed!', {body:'TEST'});
        });
    }
  });
```

This is my code in `main.js`

It comes to `console.log('blaxblux')`, but doesn't show the notification at all. Request permission works as browser shows a popup with allow button.

What things could be the issues?

(I am using latest version of chrome)

Comment: you show a notification when the service worker receives a notification. It is not a native alternative for showing messages within the UI :(

Comment: my final intention is that, but the same thing happens from service worker. notification doesn't get shown.

Answer (score 26):

I had a similar problem, but had notifications turned off on my Windows machine for Google Chrome. I went ahead and enabled notifications and they magically started working.

```
Settings -> System -> Notifications & Actions
```

Scroll down to the "Get Notifications from these Senders" section and verify "Google Chrome" (or your preferred browser) is set to "On"

Comment: OMG I knew it for the first time in 3 days

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this article can help https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/push-notifications/subscribing-a-user#requesting_permission

> The API for getting permission recently changed from taking a callback
>   to returning a Promise. The problem with this, is that we can't tell
>   what version of the API is implemented by the current browser, so you
>   have to implement both and handle both.

```
function askPermission() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const permissionResult = Notification.requestPermission(function(result) {
      resolve(result);
    });

    if (permissionResult) {
      permissionResult.then(resolve, reject);
    }
  })
  .then(function(permissionResult) {
    if (permissionResult !== 'granted') {
      throw new Error('We weren\'t granted permission.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: It's still not working. here is how i changed the code. https://gist.github.com/novaknole/5594c3603257cbd62dd3e377548a9ec1

Comment: Can you check did your service worker successfully registered?

Answer (score 0):

This was originally by Asaf but I think it's worth mentioning.

Windows has a "Focus Assist" that will hide chrome notifications. A full guide to turning it off is here:
https://www.howtogeek.com/435349/how-to-disable-windows-10s-annoying-focus-assist-notifications/

The quick was is just to search "Focus Assist" and then turn it to off.